# How to access a resource from a service in another tenant using MSI?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity, azure-service-principal

I have an azure resource that is running in tenantA.
I have a service in tenantB that needs access to the resource in the tenantA.

What are my options to achieve this other than using the raw username/pass or accesskey ? Is multi-tenant app registration in tenantA an option ? How can this be setup?

Comment: I answered (or commented on) a similar question a few days ago but now I am not able to find it. Simple answer is that you can't. MSI is specific for a particular tenant and Azure Subscription. You would have to register your service in tenantA.

Comment: how about using an app registration? I believe there is a way to create a multi tenant app in tenantA and have a representation of that in tenantB... i am not sure if and how this can be setup

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a multi-tenant application to achieve this.

Since you are trying to access an Azure resource in another tenant, I am guessing there is no user involvement, and this is an app only flow?

If so, here are some quick steps to achieve this:

1. Create the app registration in TenantB.
2. Add the application to TenantA
3. Configure the azure resource in TenantA, to grant permissions to this application.
4. The application in TenantB can now access the Azure resource in TenantA.

I wrote a blog post that has more details on this at https://blog.identitydigest.com/cross-tenant-access/... it includes a small code sample to showcase how to access key vault and Microsoft graph

Answer (score 1):

Can I use a managed identity to access a resource in a different directory/tenant

Answer is **No** , [Managed Identify in cross directory/tenant scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-faq#can-i-use-a-managed-identity-to-access-a-resource-in-a-different-directorytenant)

However you can use service principal (app registration is part of process) to enable that, i suggest you read and know the difference from https://thomasthornton.cloud/2020/10/14/azure-managed-identities-and-service-principals/ , great article !

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't explain how to do the app registrations to connect to a resource in a different tenant